# Adding Extra Add to cart button below Woocommerce Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to achieve one of either 2 things, what ever one is fine:

Add another 'add to cart' button along with the quantity option right below the price on a single product in woo. The main thing with this is that it has to match the css of the other add to cart button that is below product short description.

Or, I can just move the whole add to cart button along with its quantity option to below the price instead of below the product short description.

Hope that someone has an idea of how I could achieve either one of these :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following line of code, it will go in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
```